# CSS Horizontal Elements without Linebreak?

Tags: html, css

I have trouble to build the following in CSS.

[image]

The problem is that I did not get the green box to the full size of the yellow container as shown in the image. Also, if the label is to long it should not break the structure.

I tried:

```
<div id="c1">
    <div id="c2">test</div>
    <div id="c3">test</div>        
</div>
```

My css:

```
#c1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
}

#c2 {
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   margin: 10px;
   background-color: blue;
   display: inline-block; 
}

#c3 {
   background-color: green;
   display: inline-block;  
   height: 30px;
}
```

Here is a JsFiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/32RGz/

Comment: this could help you ? http://jsfiddle.net/32RGz/1/

Comment: @kevpoccs not it does not help c3 should not be of fixed width!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices- you must either give c2 and c3 specific widths, or use the CSS table model.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32RGz/3/)

HTML

```
 <div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Something quite long</div>  
        <div class='cell'>
            here is some moreSomething quite long that should exceed the table cell.Something quite long that should exceed the table cell.
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
.row{
    display:table-row;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    border:6px solid yellow;
}
.cell:first-child{
    width:30px;
    background:blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.cell:last-child{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background:green;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the context isn't clear but try adding width to #c3. width:80% for example

Answer (score 0):

Hows this work for ya?

http://jsfiddle.net/32RGz/2/

I added so extra margins and add a width percentage:

```
#c3 {
    display:inline-block;
   background-color: green;
   height: 30px;
    width:85%;
    float:left;
       margin-top: 10px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/32RGz/9/

```
#c1 {
    width: 400px;
    display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#c2, #c3 {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 30px;
    border: 20px solid yellow;
}
#c2 {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#c3 {
    background-color: green;
}
```